# Fast way to extract ROIs in 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 1D array that contains some video data:

```
data=np.random.randint(0,high=255,size=(500*500*100),dtype=np.uint8)
imgs=np.reshape(data,(100, 500,500)) # 100 frames, 500x500 pixels
```

I want to extract certain regions of interest (roi) along all the frames

```
idx=np.random.randint(0,high=500*500,size=(49, 300)) #300 rois, 49 points each
rois=imgs.reshape(100, -1)[:,idx]
```

I flattened each frame and then took rois along 1st dimension. The real `imgs` array is larger than the shown here and the previous indexing operation can be a bit slow. If I reshape `imgs` in a different way (se below), `rois.size` is the same and the indexing is much faster, but this retrieves the wrong data

```
%timeit imgs.reshape(100, -1)[:,idx] # 13 ms
%timeit imgs.reshape(-1, 100)[idx, :] # 1.2 ms, much faster but wrong data
```

In my real code the difference is almost 50x. Is there any way to index `imgs` fast?

Answer (score 1):

It seems one can save at least a bit of time by sorting the ROI pixels and working with transposed coordinates:

```
>>> def f_pp(im2D, idx):
...     s = np.argsort(idx.ravel())
...     out = np.empty((*idx.shape, im2D.shape[0]), im2D.dtype)
...     out.reshape(-1, im2D.shape[0])[s] = im2D.T[idx.ravel()[s]]
...     return out
... 

# results are the same:
>>> np.all(f_pp(imgs.reshape(100, -1), idx) == np.moveaxis(imgs.reshape(100, -1)[:, idx], 0, 2))
True

>>> timeit("imgs.reshape(100, -1)[:, idx]", globals=globals(), number=100)
1.3392871069954708
# transposing alone is not enough:
>>> timeit("imgs.reshape(100, -1).T[idx]", globals=globals(), number=100)
1.3336799899989273
# but together with sorting I see a 2x speedup
>>> timeit("f_pp(imgs.reshape(100, -1), idx)", globals=globals(), number=100)
0.5874412529956317
# still much worse than if we had a more favorable memory layout in
# the first place
>>> timeit("imgs.reshape(-1, 100)[idx]", globals=globals(), number=100)
0.06296327701420523
```